Inertia, Infinite Scroll - API or Web Routes?
If i'm using Inertia like this:
This is a web route:
 public function index()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Posts/Index', [
            'posts' => Post::cursorPaginate(20),
        ]);
    }

But on that page have infinite scroll, should the infinite scroll script call an API route for subsequent data?

If you are using axios on the frontend, this will allow you to load data properly.
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Http\Resources\PostResource;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Inertia\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection;

public function index(Request $request): AnonymousResourceCollection|Response
{
    $posts = Post::latest()->cursorPaginate();

    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return PostResource::collection($posts);
    }

    return Inertia::render('Posts/Index', [
        'posts' => PostResource::collection($posts),
    ]);
}

